# How to install the android app again and again without uninstalling the previous version?

Tags: android

I'm working on an android project, and I have to install it many times to test on virtual device. But at the end of yesterday, I can't re-install the app on the virtual device and this morning I find the solution, just uninstall the app and re-install it. That works for me, but now I have to uninstall and re-install it every time if I want to test.

So is there any solution to make it work like before? Install the app again and again without having to uninstall it.

Comment: When you say it doesn't install, do you mean it just won't install, or it force closes evertime?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`adb install -r appname.apk` -- the `-r` option says to replace the existing app. If you don't use -r, you must increase the version in your manifest in order to install over the top of the  previous one.

Comment: Thank you for your quickly answer. But I'm very new in Android and I don't know how to use this command. Could you show me more detail?

Comment: The "adb" command is a part of the Android SDK you downloaded, and it's the tool you use to interact with your device on a development level. http://www.xda-developers.com/android/adb-easy-tutorial/ may be of interest to you.